# Why isn't JavaScript getting the whole input box?

Tags: javascript, input, for-loop

I have some input boxes *(which are dynamically generated)* that are supposed to have numbers entered into them and add those numbers then print that on the page.

It works, but when you type a number, it doesn't get the last digit *(meaning if the number is 1-9, it will not show anything. If its **183**, the JS function, for some reason, only gets **18**)*.

This is the js function. I'm 90% sure the following code contains the error:

```
var lengthNum = document.createElement("strong");
function getLength() {
    var allNums = document.getElementsByName("numField");
    var length = 0;
    for (i=allNums.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
        length += parseInt(allNums[i].value);
    }
    if (length >= 0) {
        lengthNum.innerHTML = length;
        document.getElementById("length").appendChild(lengthNum);
    }
}
```

Comment: That code looks pretty okay. Can you give some more context? How are you submitting? I.e., where are you calling `getLength()`?

Comment: Can you provide the relevant HTML bits as well?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, your code is correct and is working fine.  See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FcF24/) for an example using the code you've provided.

Be sure that you have:

- Properly defined the `name` attribute on the textboxes that you wish to include in your total
- Not constricted the style of the output element (the div with `id="length"`) to truncate the text

Answer (score 0):

If the getLength function is being called during a keypress event, then it's possible that the function is executing before the textfield is actually given the new character.